# getting a column by "name" in an activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, select

I have a select statement that returns a field in a table.

```
records = Product.select("DISTINCT #{iFieldName}").where("id in (0, #{iInClaws})" )
```

I want to convert the data in the database to an array to be used later.. say as another inClaws.

```
records.each{|record| fieldArray << record.?????}
```

I have two questions.

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. If there's not, then how do I get the data out of the field.

---

Thanks to all.. 
After everyone came to help my final method looked like this.

```
def self.getFieldArray(iFieldName, iIDsInClaws, iIdFieldName = 'id')
    records = self.select("DISTINCT #{iFieldName}").where("#{iIdFieldName} in (#{iIDsInClaws})" )
    return records.map{|record| record.send(iFieldName)};
end
```

Comment: yes I come from a c++ background :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fieldArray = records.map(&:iFieldName)
```

Or

```
res = records.map{|r| r.send(iFieldName)}
```

Comment: Yes, you can use any method in there, since iFieldName is a method to access an attribute, it should work. But I'm actually not sure what does `records` actually, so you will have to test it for your self

Comment: undefined method `iFieldName'  for the active record class. I actually expected that.

Comment: records.each{|record| array << record.read_attribute(iFieldName)}  works, but I'm loving the "map" idea.

Comment: It's odd, it should work if `record.send(iFieldName)`, I think it's supposed to do the same, unless AtiveRecord::Relation.. has a different implementation of map

Comment: anyway, you can still do `res = records.map{|r| r.send(iFieldName)}`

Comment: Please edit your answer to include that last idea..  It's the smoothest.

Answer (score 2):

```
records.each{|record| fieldArray << record.send(iFieldName)}
```

Comment: thanks..  I picked the other answer, but yours was just as good. There was just a convo with the other one.

Comment: @RadBrad I upvoted because I used your answer to do mine and I like your profile bio

Comment: @'dave at flow', Does your wife complain about lack of sex?  Do your knee joints creek when you climb stairs?  Do you know the difference between Unix System III and Unix system V?  Just how old do you think you are?